# Email alternative without password service (anything@thedomain.com)

Tags: email

Not quite programming, but someone here will know what I'm talking about and didn't know where else to go. A while ago I found an online service that basically let you sign-up with $anything@theiraddress.com. You could then go to their website and login by using $anything and didn't need a password. The message would be available for 1 or 2 days or so.

I somehow lost the address and loved the idea/service. Can anyone point me in the right direction again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[www.mailinator.com](http://www.mailinator.com). Used it a lot for debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the one. Debugging is also why I use it and it's awesome. Couldn't believe I lost it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about

http://www.mailinator.com/
or 
http://www.maileater.com/

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [mytrashmail.com](http://mytrashmail.com/), you can just do anything @mailmetrash.com and then check it without issue.  You can even create a temporary private one (password protected) on the fly.